# Radio button- Change action/sign when selected

Tags: css, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity form for a product. I've successfully removed the radio button (as I'd like to use the images as buttons instead).

The only way it indicates something has been selected, is by making the text bold.

This is not obvious enough.

Here is the [site](http://yarnball.net.au/?product=test1)

Can I add a green TICK or somehow give the selected image a border?

Here's what I mean [Screenshot](http://yarnball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: The link to the site takes you to a coming soon page with no radio buttons. So could you please maybe post the code here?

Comment: I've added my site [here](http://yarnball.net.au/?product=test1). Please help me out- i found www.csscheckbox.com which allows me to create any radio dials I like- but pasting that CSS & JS didn't work.

Comment: didn't understand your goal

Comment: This screenshot should explain it better- [screenshot](http://yarnball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Untitled.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague, as we don't have a lot of information about the end result.  However, I've done this many times, and here's how it could be done:

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  } /* Change cursor when the label is hovered */

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  } /* Hide the ugly default radio styling */

label > span {
  display: none;
  } /* Hide the checkmark by default */

input[type=radio]:checked + span{
display: inline;
  color: green;
  } /* Show the checkmark when the radio is checked */
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="obvious"><span>✓</span> I'm rather obvious.</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="obvious"><span>✓</span> I'm rather obvious.</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="obvious"><span>✓</span> I'm rather obvious.</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="obvious"><span>✓</span> I'm rather obvious.</label>
```

I hope this helps.  If you need anything else, comment below.

Comment: Thanks- I've placed the CSS in my custom CSS section of my theme. Where abouts do I place the HTML code?

Comment: Is there a custom HTML part of your theme?

Comment: There is no Custom HTML- only custom JS and CSS.

Comment: No custom HTML part of my theme. So I got the "ADD TO ALL" Wordpress plugin. However it did not work- it did not change all my Radio buttons globally. See my site for info (bottom of the page) [link] (http://yarnball.net.au/?product=test1)